# Encrypted Communication in Java SWT WebBrowser

Tags: java, encryption, browser, swt

I want to use the [SWT WebBrowser](https://gist.github.com/caprica/6890618) to display an Website in an Java Panel. The important requirement is, that the communication of the Webbrowser to the custom server should be encrypted.

Is this possible with SWT Browser, If possible at which point should I begin.

If it's not possible, is there another easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The SWT browser is just Mozilla / IE / Safari depending on your platform, and works in the same way as they do.

Comment: so i should use https?